# Reason for name parameter in ets:new for unnamed tables

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

Looking at the documentation for [`ets:new`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#ghlink-new-2-id365845) I see that the `Name` parameter is mandatory. Also when the options contain `named_table`, the function will return the Name instead of the table identifier, which is then used to access the table.

However, when the table is not named, what is the Name parameter good for? Why is it mandatory? Do I ever use it after the table has been created? Isn't the table identifier used instead of the name then?

What is the purpose of the `Name` when the table is not named?

Answer (score 4):

This is a common practice in [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang); for unnamed tables `Name` is simply ignored.

The clause `new(Options) -> tid() | atom()`  for unnamed tables would require the additional check whether `Options` *do not contain `named_table` now*, the existing arity 2 function would require the alternative check for `named_table` is passed etc.

This all brings unnecessary complexity for no value.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!
Tend to disagree on the no added value though: clearly communicating dependencies of a function to the caller has value.
I think `new(Options) -> tid()` and `new_named(Name, Options) -> atom()` would be better in that case.

Comment: +2 redundant check I mentioned above + redundant private function for shared functionality + a necessity to support 2 documentation clauses... KISS. Unused arguments are often ignored in [tag:erlang], it’s a matter of simplicity.

Comment: The name is not completely ignored - you can get it with `ets:info(Tid, name)`. I can't think of any sensible way to use that "feature", though...

Comment: Interesting, I perceive this as more complicated (at least for the consumer). But having a single function to create a new table is also a good point. Guess I still need to adapt to the erlang way :)
Thanks again!